# trackpad needs two fingers to move mouse, won't scroll on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling

All of a sudden my trackpad has changed it's behavior on a windows 10 Lenovo that hasn't had any updates today.

Before it could scroll by holding both fingers down and scrolling, now no scrolling - In Settings `Trackpad -> Scroll and Zoom -> Drag two fingers to scroll` is selected.

Before it could move the mouse cursor with one hand, now it cannot, now it takes two fingers to move the mouse cursor.

I would like if I move one finger on the trackpad that the mouse cursor moves, and if possible that I could scroll content by the use the trackpad in some way. Now I basically have to go to the scrollbar to click it or use the arrow keys.

Also since this happened out of the blue I suppose it is because of some awful idiotic shortcut to screw up your settings that MS has enabled, how do I remove this shortcut and hopefully the ability to every call that shortcut again in the future.

Comment: Did you spill something on the touchpad?

Comment: no, I also restarted and didn't have any change. then about some hours later it went b back to working the way it was before. I leave the question open because hopefully if someone has an idea how to stop it that will show me how to replicate it  and hopefully to stop it from ever happening again.

Comment: Was the humidity high? This seems like a hardware issue, particularly since it fixed itself.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds stupid, but try just closing your lid and waiting a few seconds. Worked for me

Comment: Thank you, worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me as well

Comment: Crazy, worked also for me.

Comment: Solved the issue for me. I had it before with Windows 10, now it just happened with Windows 11 (sigh).

Comment: Wow - this just happened to me and I was checking devices and settings and all the deeper troubleshooting but yeah, closing the lid fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me regularly with Windows 10 also on a Lenova. All of a sudden it shifts from 1 finger scroll to 2 finger scroll even tho the box on the settings page is unclicked. I just click and reclick it for awhile and it eventually goes back but is super annoying. If this is something I am triggering I would like to find out what it is so I can make it stop. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1174895)